# parse mac address by using python

Tags: r, python-3.x, pcap

I am new user to python and R. I have retrieved the data from pcap file for detecting anomalies.
eth.src  00:0c:29:ee:b7:84  eth.dst 00:0c:29:6e:ba:5e

These the example of two fields in dataframe. I would like to parse the mac addresses and create a matrix of the values and then represent in graph represention by using R.

I am stuck at parsing mac addresses. I am thinking of using Regular expressions for parsing. Is there any library available for this? I need a little help and guidance in this area. Thank you.

Comment: This is too broad.  Formulate a focused problem that either involves R or python but not both and then provide input, expected output and your code attempt.  Please review [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I will check and post.